# Summing an array within a column using the aggregate function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to sum a field which contains an array,

```
a = sc.parallelize([("a", [1,1,1]),
                    ("a", [2,2])])

a = a.toDF(["g", "arr_val"])

a.registerTempTable('a')

sql = """
select 
aggregate(arr_val, 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x) as sum
from a
"""

spark.sql(sql).show()
```

But I'm running into the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o24.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'aggregate(a.`arr_val`, 0, lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS BIGINT) + namedlambdavariable()), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()), lambdafunction(namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()))' due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires int type, however, 'lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS BIGINT) + namedlambdavariable()), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable())' is of bigint type.; line 3 pos 0;
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the values within the accumulator e.g. to a float:

```
a = sc.parallelize([("a", [1,1,1]),
                    ("a", [2,2])])
a = a.toDF(["g", "arr_val"])

a.registerTempTable('a')

sql = """
select 
aggregate(arr_val, cast(0 as float), (acc, x) -> acc + cast(x as float)) as sum
from a
"""

spark.sql(sql).show()
```